# Problema de CORS con Django DRF

Tags: djangorestframework, cors

Un saludo para todos, actualmente estoy trabajando en una API con Django Rest Framework y un frontend con React (create react app) y se me ha presentado un inconveniente con la política de CORS.

Instalé el paquete `django-cors-headers==3.11.0`

Y lo configuré de la siguiente manera

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://dev-ct.portubien.co/",
    "http://cerotramites.portubien.co:88/"
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
```

El primero `"https://dev-ct.portubien.co/"` corresponde al entorno de pruebas de desarrollo y allí quedó solucionado.

Sin embargo en el segundo `"http://cerotramites.portubien.co:88/"` no sucedió lo mismo, el error de CORS persiste.

Tanto backend como frontend tienen su respectivo entorno de pruebas y de producción

Pruebas

```
https://dev-ct.portubien.co/ -> https://dev-rcv.portubien.co/
```

Producción

```
http://cerotramites.portubien.co:88/ -> http://app.portubien.co:88/
```

Consola Dev Tools
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Network Dev Tools
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco a quien me pueda informar que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, si me hace falta configurar algo mas o cualquier otra situación que me pueda ayudar a solventar la situación

**Nota:**
El servidor de producción tiene implementado `APACHE` en el puerto `80` debido a que ya existen proyectos implementados allí. En mi caso uso `UWSGI` como servidor web para correr `Django` y a `Nginx` lo tengo como servidor proxy, por tal motivo `Nginx` esta habilitado por el puerto `88` en el entorno de producción.

Comment: Cual es el error exacto que te aparece?

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con una captura del el error que estoy obteniendo en la consola del navegador.

Comment: Ahora abre WebDev Tools, anda a network tab, y revisa los response headers del request que carga la pagina, para ver si el header de CORS esta correcto, puedes postear el screenshot tambien

Comment: Nueva actualización con las capturas de networks

Comment: Lo que necesitas ver son los `Response Headers` del request a `http://cerotramites.portubien.co:88/`, no a `/api/token`, dado que el request principal desde donde se cargan los otros recursos es el primero que menciono

Comment: Nueva actualización con las capturas de networks response

Comment: Sigues haciendo screenshot del request a token, no de la pagina principal. `/api/token` es un request adicional después del request inicial

Comment: Nueva actualización con las capturas de networks login

Answer (score 0):

Como puedes ver en el último screenshot que tienes en tu post, el request a `/login` no esta devolviendo ningún CORS header ya que lo esta sirviendo Nginx.

Lo que tienes que hacer es agregar uno o más CORS headers en tu configuración de Nginx, por ejemplo:

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'app.portubien.co:88';
}
```

Como referencia, si necesitas una configuración mas detallada, puedes usar esta como referencia:

```
#
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
     }
}
```

Fuente: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: Hola, ya hice la implementación y continua igual.

Comment: Que response headers aparecen en el request ahora?